# ASN.1 BER encoding

Tags: asn.1

1 syntax. when i am encoding this syntax to BER, not providing correct results.

i am using OSS ASN.1 Stdio to compile the asn.1 syntax

```
SignDoc DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= BEGIN

OneSignature ::= SEQUENCE {
signTime UTCTime,
signature BIT STRING,
certificate BIT STRING
}


first-Doc OneSignature ::={

        signTime "130223064540Z",
        signature '0111010001100101011100110111010000100000'B,
        certificate '0111010001100101011100110111010000100000'B

}

  END
```

and BER Encoding result is :

```
30 1F
   80 0D 3133303232333036343534305A
   81 06 007465737420
   82 06 007465737420
```

Is this is correct result ?

we require the result of BER encoding is :

```
30 1F
   23 0D 3133303232333036343534305A
   03 06 007465737420
   03 06 007465737420
```

Please provide the suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should send your questions about the OSS Tools directly to OSS Technical support (support@oss.com).  In this case, I suspect if you remove "AUTOMATIC TAGS" at the top of the ASN.1 module, you will get the results you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion kindly provide some tool name. to encode asn.1 to BER. and i'll try to remove AUTOMATIC TAGS but it is not compile in oss tool. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

The first one is "Automatic Tagged" IMPLICIT. The second one is "Not Tagged"

They are both correct depends on the definition.

Since you definition has this "AUTOMATIC TAGS", the first one is the correct result if "IMPLICIT" is the module default. Please check this link for more information:
https://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/asn1-made-simple/asn1-quick-reference/asn1-tags.html